# From where the label displayed on the network interface comes from?

Tags: windows, networking, network-adapter

In the Windows Network Connections image we see four network interfaces.

[image]

The Wi-Fi have a label showing the wifi network `zircon401` to which it is connected, while the VirtualBox one shows `Enabled`. The Bluetooth says `Not connected`.

And `Ethernet 6`, which is connected to a device, and shows `Network 3`.

Where these labels come from? How can I modify them?

I guess on Linux/macOS they will show up also.

Comment: https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/rename_a_network_adapter_in_windows.html

Comment: Removed linux & macOS tags. The question has nothing to do with either, except for an unfounded assumption.